# XSL transformation problem due to xmlns

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm having a issue with a XSLT transformation that doesn't want to work when the data-source uses a specific xmlns.

What am I doing wrong here? (The transformation itself is done by our SAP MII enterpricy system)

*XSL*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:s="http://www.wbf.org/xml/b2mml-v02"
    exclude-result-prefixes="s">

    <xsl:output method="html"
                omit-xml-declaration="yes"
                encoding="UTF-8"
                indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
       <xsl:value-of select="s:/ProductionSchedule/ID" />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

*Data*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ProductionSchedule
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns="http://www.wbf.org/xml/b2mml-v02">
    <ID>000003037668</ID>
    <Location>
        <EquipmentID>UK14</EquipmentID>
        <EquipmentElementLevel>Site</EquipmentElementLevel>
    </Location>
    <PublishedDate>2010-09-28T11:08:04</PublishedDate>
    ...
</ProductionSchedule>
```

Comment: "a XSLT transformation that doesn't want to work when the data-source uses a specific xmlns" - the XSLT shown should not work regardless of the data source (input document). The XPath expression `s:/ProductionSchedule/ID` should give a syntax error. Didn't it?

Comment: No, the Java based parser that SAP uses just crashed. Somewhat typical for Java Enterprise stuff :p

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`<xsl:value-of select="/s:ProductionSchedule/s:ID" />`

Comment: Thanks a lot, i was struggling to solve it from last 2 hours, finally its working now :)